# Execute groovy script with shell

Tags: shell, unix, groovy

I am trying to execute a groovy script on a unix environnement but i have an issue, I don't know how to write a shell script that could execute the script under :

```
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ModelService;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchService;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.SearchResult;
import com.galerieslafayette.pcm.model.model.product.RmsProductModel ;

final FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService = spring.getBean("flexibleSearchService");
final ModelService modelService = spring.getBean("modelService");

new File("/tmp/productsToUpdate.csv").splitEachLine(";") {fields -> 
  criteria = fields[1]

  if (fields[2]?.trim()) {
      criteria += "</p><p>" + fields[2]
  }

  if (fields[3]?.trim()) {
      criteria += "</p><p>" + fields[3]
  }

  criteria = "<p>" + criteria + "</p>"

  updateProduct(fields[0], criteria)
}


def updateProduct(ugProduct, criteria) {
    SearchResult<RmsProductModel> result = flexibleSearchService.search("select {pk} from {RmsProduct} where {ug}=?ugCode", ["ugCode":ugProduct]);
    if(result.getResult().get(0) != null){
        RmsProductModel rmsProduct = result.getResult().get(0);
    String temp = rmsProduct.getProduct().getDescription(Locale.FRANCE);
    rmsProduct.getProduct().setDescription(temp + criteria, Locale.FRANCE)
    modelService.save(rmsProduct.getProduct());
    }
}
```

I tried to find on the web how to do so, but i only find subject on how to run shell in a groovy and not the opposite.

I am a beginner on unix and don't know the command line or if i need a specifique addition on my environnement or if vanilla shell could do it

Comment: do you have groovy and java installed on a computer where you want to run it? can you run `groovy -version` command? if yes, then just run: `groovy MyScript.groovy`

Comment: we do have java but we do not have the groovy executor installed, this is why i try to find a way with a nativ shell script running the script

Comment: in any case you have to install groovy http://groovy-lang.org/install.html#_install_binary Then, if you want to run groovy directly from shell, you can add this line to the top of your groovy script: `#!/usr/bin/env groovy`